# Android Socket Programming: AsyncTask for sending real-time data

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm doing socket programming. Whenever a user touches the screen, the touch position is sent to my server. But at times, there is a delay of up to 5 seconds in sending this data from my client android app to my server .My question is that is there any possibility that because a larger number of AsyncTasks are being executed when the user touches the screen, so may be the delay is due to this? If that's not the case, I'd also attach the server side code. Here is my client side code:

**EDIT:** Updated code

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 50) {
        lastUpdate = curTime;

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        String msg = x + " " + y + " " + "<EOF>";
        new Client().execute(msg);
    }

    return false;
}

private class Client extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... messages) {
        Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, 1755);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println(messages[0]);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Now, I send the touch position after every 50 milliseconds. But its effect on server end is laggy. If I set the interval to be less than 50, say 20, the same problem persists. That is, there is delay of up to 5 seconds. Any solution? Also, I guess that interval must be set according to each device?

Comment: Why are you always closing the socket ?

Comment: I just found an example and followed it. I'm beginner in socket programming.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this wrong. First, if you are running on pre HONEYCOMB, having "touchy" user you will end up with tons of AsyncTasks **running in parallel** trying to reach your end point at the same time, keeping opened sockets, consuming resources. There's also no guarantee you will receive the data in the same order your tasks were started (not to mention error handling). From other hand, if you are running on HONEYCOMB, then you will end up with tons of AsyncTasks queued, awaiting for execution. Neither way is the way to go and you should cache the data (store your touches in database locally on the device), and then run networking code from time to time (i.e. once the number or records in DB hits the threshold or X minutes passed) and send all the data from DB in one bigger request.

**EDIT**

> In my server app, I want to move my object as the user moves his finger in client app

You need to rethink the approach then and use "events" if possible, otherwise your server app would be rather sluggish. So I'd rather try to avoid doing i.e. "dragging" by sending each X,Y during the drag, but instead I would just create "moveTo" event and send `moveTo object Z to X,Y` so my server app would be able to update state of the objects.

**EDIT 2**

> You will not be able to animate object dragging on your server app that way but that's only disadvantage. Yes, that's my point. Unfortunately, the primary goal of server app is to animate

Then you will most likely need to buffer your data anyway. Also **single** networking task to send events in order. You may want to do some "filtering" anyway to limit number of coords per time unit (to i.e. avoid rapid moves and 100 coords pair in 1 sec).

Comment: In my case, I want to react to those touches in real-time.

Comment: In my server app, I want to move my object as the user moves his finger in client app, so is there any other alternative so that I can send the data faster?

Comment: Can you give me an idea? I'm not asking for code, just a direction.

Comment: Doesn't the problem still persist? What happens in server app when the user is still dragging the object? What if that dragging process takes 5 seconds? Won't the object start to be dragged after 5 seconds?

Comment: You mean with "event" approach"? Nothing happens after 5, 10 nor 100 seconds, because you will create "drag" event only at the time drag event is completed by user. You will not be able to animate object dragging on your server app that way but that's only disadvantage. In fact "drag" name of event may be misleading. It should rather be "move". I edited the answer to reflect that

Comment: **You will not be able to animate object dragging on your server app that way but that's only disadvantage.** Yes, that's my point. Unfortunately, the primary goal of server app is to animate.

Comment: Is there any alternative to AsyncTask to tackle this problem?

Comment: AsyncTask is not the problem here. Your approach is. See my edited answer

Comment: I'd give it a try and get back to you.